# Are there any patterns for reducing method counts?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, code-organization

There is a class, which has two methods.
(Full source can be found [here](https://github.com/dance2die/Project.MyAnimeList/blob/master/Project.MyAnimeList/Project.MyAnimeList/Facade/SearchMethods.cs))

```
public string SearchAnime(string searchTerm)
{
    // returns string
}

public AnimeSearchResponse SearchAnimeDeserialized(string searchTerm)
{
    // returns an AnimeSearchResponse type object instance
}
```

I am trying to create Asynchronous versions of above two methods. 
That would mean methods like `SearchAnimeAsync` and `SearchAnimeDeserializedAsync` need to be created.

There is a plan to add more `SearchAnime*` methods that return XML or JSON data. 
As I add more `SearchAnime*` methods, the number of methods will increase two folds due to Async counterparts. 
(SearchAnimeXml & SearchAnimeXmlAsync and SearchAnimeJson & SearchAnimeJsonAsync)

It gets worse because the class also contains `SearchManga` and `SearchMangaDeserialized`, for which I will create Async versions.

Are there any solutions or design patterns that'd ease the explosion of methods?

Comment: Since we don't have any idea what those methods actually *do*, we can't fit them into any pattern, which makes this question too broad.

Comment: I'd expect most services framework will provide "magical" serialization solution (i.e. WebAPI)... Also consider to simplify your life by not having synchronous   versions. That will give you exactly one method :)

Comment: @Alexei That really depends on who's going to be calling that code. Sometimes `async` where it isn't possible can make more trouble than do good.

Comment: you can merge `SearchAnime` and `SearchManga`. for example change signature to `public string Search(string searchTerm, SearchType enum)` and use condition inside method.

Comment: The best way I know about how to decrease number of methods in a class is to increase number of classes :). See @Kapol's answer for example.

Comment: If seriously (as before) you can make methods more `generic` like changing parameter from string searchTerm to Filter filter, where filter can specify not only search term but also anime type and whether deserialization is needed or not. Also you can make return value more generic. Like include not decerialized string in a SearchResponse class if in filter it was specified that decerialization is not needed.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov somewhat agree. OP should implement 2 completely parallel implementations for each method - one completely synchronous and another completely asynchronous. And test both. And not cut corners with `Task<T>.Result`/`Task.Wait`, `ConfigureAwait(false)` or `Task.Run(...)`. (I'm fine with that as it is not me who have to implement that :) )

Answer (score 3):

One solution that comes to my mind is to create a `Searcher` abstract base class (with methods `Search` and `SearchAsync`) and a `ISearchResponse` interface (specifying behavior common to all responses). Then each of the `Searcher`-derived classes would have only two exposed methods.

```
public interface ISearchResponse
{
    void Foo();
}

public class AnimeSearchResponse : ISearchResponse
{
    public void Foo() {}
}

public abstract class Searcher
{
    abstract ISearchResponse Search();
    abstract ISearchResponse SearchAsync();
}

public class AnimeSearcher : Searcher
{
    public override ISearchResponse Search(string searchTerm)
    {
        return new AnimeSearchResponse(searchTerm);
    }

    public override ISearchResponse SearchAsync(string searchTerm)
    {
        return new AnimeSearchResponse(searchTerm);
    }
}
```

You will end up with a lot of classes instead of a lot of methods, but the advantage is that the derived types will be more specialized and can be substituted easily by one another if needed. Somewhere in the application you can choose which concrete type of `Searcher` you want to use, using for example the *Factory method* design pattern.